# Swing application framework for multilanguage application

Tags: java, swing, multilingual

Can the swing application framework be used to implement multilanguage swing applications?
If so, how should it be done? Should I use multiple .properties files, one for each language? How can I let the system know which properties file to use then? Does anybody know a good tutorial for this?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this a question about JSR-296 "Swing Application Framework", or just about programming in plain-old vanilla Swing?  I have assumed it's about JSR-296 in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the following in your base panel class (or anywhere else, and plug it in):

```
public ResourceMap getResourceMap() {
    if (resourceMap == null) {
        ApplicationContext context = getContext();
        if (context != null) {
            resourceMap = context.getResourceMap(getResourceStartClass(), 
                   getResourceStopClass());
        }
    }

    return resourceMap;
}

public ApplicationContext getContext() {
    if (applicationContext == null) {
        Application app = getApplication();
        if (app != null) {
            applicationContext = app.getContext();
        }
    }

    return applicationContext;
}

public Application getApplication() {
    if (application == null) {
        application = Application.getInstance();
    }

    return application;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This works for me, together with having the correct name for the properties files...

Although it looks a bit weird you apply the singleton pattern in your getApplication() method. This looks like overhead to me. Why don't you just call 'Application.getInstance()' here?

Comment: it's some kind of lazy loading. I got this from an old codebase, so if Application.getInstance() is itself lazy, you can omit that method.

Answer (score 1):

take a look to the [ResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class and [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html).

**NB**: this class is not tied to Swing, you can use it in console or web applications)

Answer (score 0):

Original project is dead now, but you can use a fork of it. The most active one is [BSAF](http://kenai.com/projects/bsaf).

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: yes it can, and yes you should.

Here's a short bit of user-friendly blurb on it:
http://chaoticjava.com/posts/the-quiet-revolution-part-i-jsr-296/

However, a word of warning: According to the web-site for the JSR
http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=296
It is currently *inactive*.